# Convert datatable to list of generic type

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable

How to convert datatable into list of generic type. Below is the scenario.
I have datatable with name `table1` and contains columns `col1,col2`. **how could we convert this table into a list of type name `table1bj`(which can be different per the datatable name) with properties col1 and col2 with compatible  datatype as of datatable column data types.**

There are many post on SO but these are with the converting datatable into predefined object list. Here in my case I have to **generate object and list dynamically** from the datatable. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use Entity Framework?

Comment: Can you tell us how you populate the DataTable? user input? bound to a collection?

Comment: @DaveRook :We are using wcf services for data access layer

Comment: @DropTheTable : I am getting datatable from the database. I want to convert it into list

Comment: @eraj, WCF Data Services and EF can go pretty well together.

Comment: @Tim answer is correct, only side note here is - consider to directly get collection of `table1bj` from database, without filling intermediate datatable

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you've already created the class `table1bj` (consider to make it uppercase due to .NET naming conventions) with two properties `col1`,`col2` (the same). You just have to use `Enumerable.Select` to create instances of this class and `ToList` to create a generic `List<table1bj>`:

```
List<table1bj> result = table1.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => new table1bj 
                       { 
                           col1 = row.Field<string>("col1"), 
                           col1 = row.Field<string>("col1") 
                       }
    ).ToList();
```

I have also presumed that these properties are `string`s, otherwise use the correct type with the `Field` extension method. If you don't know the type you should stay with your `DataTable` since it's already an in-memory collection with dynamic types.

Comment: @Time Schmelter : Please note that I do not know table1obj and its columns. This should also create dynamically from the datatable definition

Comment: @eraj: Then you cannot use a class maybe an anonymous class. But an unknown class violates the principle of a generic list, so stay with the `DataTable`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this...

**Create Class with properties :**

```
public class table1bj
    {
        public string col1{ get; set; }
        public string col2{ get; set; }
    }
```

**Convert DataTable to Generic Type :**

```
List<table1bj> Objtable1bj = table1.ToCollection<table1bj>();
```

Comment: Can you give a reference to `ToCollection<T>` method description?

Comment: It's an extension method.http://extensionmethod.net/csharp/ienumerable-t/tocollection-t

Comment: @Sangram: But it's not part of the framework, so you should post it in the answer itself instead of a link in a comment. Apart from that you cannot cast a `DataRow` to `table1bj`.

Comment: @Vishal : I want to convert datatable to list of unknown type which should be generated dynamically.

Comment: @eraj May be this blog helpful to you... `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787972/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-properly-cast-an-unknown-property-to-a-generic-list-t`

Answer (score 1):

I know this question asked many times ago, but also I need a solutions for convert data table to dynamic or generic types in one method and I can't find answer for this, so post my answer.

You can use a extension method to convert data table to any type like below:

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static IList<T> ToList<T>(this DataTable dt, bool isFirstRowColumnsHeader = false) where T : new()
    {
        var results = new List<T>();

        if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            var columns = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToList();
            var rows = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList();
            var headerNames = columns.Select(col => col.ColumnName).ToList();
            //
            // Find properties name or columns name
            if (isFirstRowColumnsHeader)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < headerNames.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (rows[0][i] != DBNull.Value && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(rows[0][i].ToString()))
                        headerNames[i] = rows[0][i].ToString();
                }

                //
                // remove first row because that is header
                rows.RemoveAt(0);
            }

            // Create dynamic or anonymous object for `T type
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject) ||
                typeof(T) == typeof(System.Dynamic.DynamicObject) ||
                typeof(T) == typeof(System.Object))
            {
                var dynamicDt = new List<dynamic>();
                foreach (var row in rows)
                {
                    dynamic dyn = new ExpandoObject();
                    dynamicDt.Add(dyn);
                    for (var i = 0; i < columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var dic = (IDictionary<string, object>)dyn;
                        dic[headerNames[i]] = row[columns[i]];
                    }
                }
                return (dynamic)dynamicDt;
            }
            else // other types of `T
            {
                var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
                if (columns.Any() && properties.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var row in rows)
                    {
                        var entity = new T();
                        for (var i = 0; i < columns.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (!row.IsNull(columns[i]))
                            {
                                typeof(T).GetProperty(headerNames[i])? // ? -> maybe the property by name `headerNames[i]` is not exist in entity then get null!
                                    .SetValue(entity, row[columns[i]] == DBNull.Value ? null : row[columns[i]]);
                            }
                        }
                        results.Add(entity);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do it by Reflection also, this method helps to set ClassObject properties by DataTable:

```
    using System.Reflection;

    public void SetObjectProperties(object objClass, DataTable dataTable)
    {
        DataRow _dataRow = dataTable.Rows[0];
        Type objType = objClass.GetType();
        List<PropertyInfo> propertyList = new List<PropertyInfo>(objType.GetProperties());

        foreach (DataColumn dc in _dataRow.Table.Columns)
        {
            var _prop = propertyList.Where(a => a.Name == dc.ColumnName).Select(a => a).FirstOrDefault();

            if (_prop == null) continue;

            _prop.SetValue(objClass, Convert.ChangeType(_dataRow[dc], Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(_prop.PropertyType) ?? _prop.PropertyType), null);
        }
    }
```