# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List TO System.Collections.Generic.IList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, linq, generics

I have the following code :

```
 public class ComputeOperationData
{
    public COUNTERS_DATA CounterData { get; set; }
    public COMPUTES_OPERATION ComputeOperation { get; set; }
    public COUNTERS_FORMULA CounterFormula { get; set; }

}

Public Function GetComputeOperationData(ByVal computeId As Integer, ByVal priodType As Integer, ByVal lstDuringTime As DuringTime) As IList(Of ComputeOperationData) Implements IComputeResultService.GetComputeOperationData
        Dim computeOperations As IQueryable(Of COMPUTES_OPERATION) = _repository.GetObjectQuery(Of COMPUTES_OPERATION).Include("COMPUTES").Include("COUNTERS")
        computeOperations = computeOperations.Where(Function(a) a.COMPUTE_ID = computeId)

        Dim countersFormula As IQueryable(Of COUNTERS_FORMULA) = _repository.GetObjectQuery(Of COUNTERS_FORMULA)().Include("COUNTERS")

        Dim countersData As IQueryable(Of DomainClasses.COUNTERS_DATA) = _repository.GetObjectQuery(Of DomainClasses.COUNTERS_DATA)().Include("COUNTERS")
        countersData = countersData.Where(Function(a) a.PERIOD_TYPE = priodType And a.COUNTER_DATE = lstDuringTime.StartDate And a.COUNTER_TIME >= lstDuringTime.StartTime And a.COUNTER_TIME <= lstDuringTime.EndTime)

                    Dim lstComputeOperationData = From counterData In countersData
                 Join computeOperation In computeOperations On counterData.COUNTER_ID Equals computeOperation.COUNTER_ID
                 Join counterFormula In countersFormula On counterData.COUNTER_ID Equals counterFormula.COUNTER_ID
                 Where counterData.COUNTER_DATE >= counterFormula.FROM_DATE And counterData.COUNTER_DATE <= counterFormula.TO_DATE




        Return lstComputeOperationData.ToList

    End Function
```

And I got this error  :

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[VB$AnonymousType_1`3[Danesh.Ems.DomainClasses.COUNTERS_DATA,Danesh.Ems.DomainClasses.COMPUTES_OPERATION,Danesh.Ems.DomainClasses.COUNTERS_FORMULA]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Danesh.Ems.Models.ComputeOperationData]'

please help me

Comment: Please expand on your problem. More detail and guidance will reward you with greater help.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I used VB.NET, but in C#, you'd need something like...

```
Select New ComputeOperationData() 
{ 
   CounterData = counterData, ComputeOperation = computeOperation, CounterFormula = counterFormula 
}
```

...at the end of your query to transform the three separate data sources into a single object.

Comment: my new query :
From counterData In countersData
                     Join computeOperation In computeOperations On counterData.COUNTER_ID Equals computeOperation.COUNTER_ID
                     Join counterFormula In countersFormula On counterData.COUNTER_ID Equals counterFormula.COUNTER_ID
                     Where counterData.COUNTER_DATE >= counterFormula.FROM_DATE And counterData.COUNTER_DATE <= counterFormula.TO_DATE
                     Select New With {.CounterData = counterData, .ComputeOperation = computeOperation, .CounterFormula = counterFormula}

but i got same error 
:-(

Comment: You're still missing the type construction.  You're creating an anonymous class, not a ComputeOperationData class like you want to return.

Answer (score 0):

You have function that return `IList(Of ComputeOperationData)` but inside you tru return `List(Of AnonymousClass)`
so in your linq query you need specify what type of object you want return, like this

```
Dim lstComputeOperationData = From counterData In countersData
                              Join computeOperation In computeOperations On counterData.COUNTER_ID Equals computeOperation.COUNTER_ID
                              Join counterFormula In countersFormula On counterData.COUNTER_ID Equals counterFormula.COUNTER_ID
                              Where counterData.COUNTER_DATE >= counterFormula.FROM_DATE And counterData.COUNTER_DATE <= counterFormula.TO_DATE
                              Select New ComputeOperationData With {.CounterData = counterData, .ComputeOperation = computeOperation, .CounterFormula = counterFormula}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you see the runtime error message: *Unable to cast object of type Generic.List [SomeDerivedType] to  Generic.IList[SomeBaseType]*, you may simply need to **Cast** the objects to the proper type in the list before making the assignment to the IList.

For example:

```
Dim objectIList As IList(Of Object)
Dim stringList As New List(Of String)
objectIList = stringList.Cast(Of Object).ToList()
```

This is tricky because the compiler does not catch this. There are several C# based questions that relate to this issue. Here is [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521818/cast-iliststring-to-ilistobject-fails-at-runtime). Here is [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase).