# Casting list of objects to List vs IList

Tags: c#, casting

Just came across this:

```
Func<List<object>> foo = () => new List<object>();
List<string> s = (List<string>)foo();
IList<string> s1 = (IList<string>)foo();
```

Compiler complains about casting to List (makes sense), but says nothing about IList. Makes me wonder why is that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that last line will fail at runtime.

Comment: It does - but its interesting that the compiler will catch the first case.

Comment: Yes, it will. Just wonder why it compiles.

Comment: @ReedCopsey, I should have stated that I am interested in the compiler error. I agree; it's very interesting.

Comment: @ReedCopsey, The compiler *knows* there is no implicit cast operation to `List<string>`, but the implementer of `IList<string>` may be able to?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The compiler knows that a `List<X>` cannot be a `List<Y>`.
It therefore gives a compiler error.

However, the second cast could succeed if the `List<X>` is actually some derived class that also implements `IList<Y>`.

You will only get a compile-time error from a cast if neither type is an interface, or if one type is an unrelated interface and the other type is sealed (or a struct).

To quote the spec (§6.4.2)

> The explicit reference conversions are:
>
> - From object and dynamic to any other reference-type.
> - From any class-type S to any class-type T, provided S is a base class of T.
> - **From any class-type S to any interface-type T, provided S is not sealed and provided S does not implement T.**
> - **From any interface-type S to any class-type T, provided T is not sealed or provided T implements S.**
> - From any interface-type S to any interface-type T, provided S is not derived from T.
> - [snip]

(emphasis added)

The `provided...` clauses exclude conversions that are actually implicit.

Comment: And the other type is `sealed`? Is that because it knows it can't be overriden by an inheritor?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: Exactly.

Comment: Hm, which makes this a valid construct: 

Func<List<object>> foo = () => new List<object>();
var s1 = (IFoo)foo();

Unexpected, really.

Comment: @Eugene: It's sometimes unexpected, but it has to be legal.  I've done this more than once this past week in real code.

Comment: Thanks for quoting the spec!

Answer (score 3):

An object that is known to be a `List<object>` might implement `IList<string>` as well as `IList<object>`, so it's possible that the cast can succeed. It can't in this case because we know that the statement is simply `new List<object>()`, but the compiler doesn't consider that. You might've extended `List<T>` and implemented the other, e.g.

```
// not recommended, but second cast works
public class MyWeirdList : List<object>, IList<string>
```

An object that is known to be a `List<object>` cannot possibly also be a `List<string>`, because you can only inherit from a single type.

```
public class MyWeirdList : List<object>, List<string> // compiler error
```

If `List<T>` were sealed, both casts would be invalid, because then the compiler would know for sure that the class couldn't implement `IList<string>`. You can try this by using this class instead:

```
public sealed class SealedList<T> : List<T> { }
```

Answer (score 1):

The first line fails at compile time, the second gives an "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.String]'." exception during runtime.

If you look at this question ([Cast IList<string> to IList<object> fails at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521818/cast-iliststring-to-ilistobject-fails-at-runtime)), the answer clarifies why this compile works and also provides an example for a class that could satisfy the conditions provided.