# Type casting in method signatures in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have 2 classes `A` and `B`. `B` inherits from `A`. If I have a method like 
`void works(A aType)` I can pass a `B` type object through just fine. However, a method like `void fails(List<A> aListType)` fails for a `List<B>` type with Visual Studio complaining that it can't convert between `List<A>` and `List<B>`. I can resolve this with generics, but why does it fail in the first place? Also, should I just be using generics instead?

Here's a basic example:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            B bType1 = new B();
            works(bType1); // This works

            List<B> bListType1 = new List<B>();
            works(bListType1); // This works

            List<B> bListType2 = new List<B>();
            fails(bListType2); // This fails
        }

        static void works(A aType)
        {
            return;
        }

        static void works<T>(List<T> aListType) where T : A
        {
            return;
        }

        static void fails(List<A> aListType)
        {
            return;
        }

    }

    class A
    {

    }

    class B : A
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10957035/1341409 . It's about Covariance and Contravariance.

Comment: `List<B>` does not inherit from `List<A>` even though `B` inherits from `A`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass a `List<B>` into `fails`, and `fails` somewhere along the line tries to add an `A` to to it (because a `List<A>` has an `void Add(A item)` method), what would you expect to happen?

```
static void Fails(List<A> items)
{
    aListType.Add(new A());
}

...

Fails(new List<B>());
```

Let's say this code compiles; it will have to explode at runtime when it tries to add an `A` to a `List<B>`. Is this a type safe operation?

If you only want to *iterate* over the `List<B>` as a `List<A>`, you should use the `IEnumerable<A>` interface. A `List<B>` *can* be treated as an `IEnumerable<A>`, since the `IEnumerable` interface is covariant.

```
static void AlsoWorks(IEnumerable<A> items)
{
    foreach(var a in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No problems here!");
    }
}

...

AlsoWorks(new List<B>());
```

Comment: If this isn't considered safe, why is using    `static void works<T>(List<T> aListType) where T : A` considered safe by the compiler? Doesn't that run into the same issue?

Comment: @Ringil That generic method call is resolving to `static void works(List<B> aListType)` when you pass in a `List<B>`. The type argument provided for the parameter `T` is `B`. It should come as no surprise that passing a `List<B>` where a `List<B>` is expected is type safe.

Answer (score 4):

That's because `List<T>` is an **Invariant** type in C#, which means you can only use the type that was originally specified in the variable definition (i.e. `A`). You'll notice that if you replace `List<A>` with `IEnumerable<A>`, your error goes away. This is because `IEnumerable<A>` is **Covariant**, meaning you can use a more derived type than originally specified (i.e. `B`). Read more about [Covariance and Contravariance in C# here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Marc Gravell has answered this before. The explanation is ideal for your understanding here of what options you have and why what you tried isnt possible.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5832173/1347784