# IList<T> contravariance and casting issue

Tags: c#, list

I have a FileRecord class with the following definition:

```
public class FileRecord
{
    public IList<IDataRecord> DataRecords { get; set; }
    public IList<ImageFile> Images { get; set; }
    public string IndexFileName { get; set; }
    public string IndexFilePath { get; set; }
}
```

please note that datarecords is a IList of an interface type.

I then have a method that creates a file record for each type of datarecords we have:

```
fileRecord = new FileRecord
{
    DataRecords = CsvFile.Read<VallDataData>(Path.GetFullPath(indexFile.FullName)).Where(x => x.GiftAidValidity == "Y").ToList<IDataRecord>()
};
```

if I remove the implicit casting on the `ToList<IDataRecord>() to ToList()` I get this error message:

```
Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<VallDataData>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<IDataRecord>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

even though VallDataData implements IDataRecord

why is this?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of `.ToList<IDataRecord>()` try this: `.Cast<IDataRecord>().ToList();`

Comment: '.ToList<IDataRecord>()' works, I'm casting back to the interface, I just want to know why I can't do just '.ToList()' if my VallDataData type implements the interface.

Comment: Because although the variable is a `IList<IDataRecord>` the actual type is still a `List<VallDataData>`, Because `IList<T>` has a `Add(T)` method I could do `fileRecord.Add(new Bar())` (Assuming `Bar` also implemented `IDataRecord`) this would cause a `Bar` to be added to a `List<VallDataData>` which is illegal.

Comment: @franklores see my answer, IList is not contravariant

Comment: Thank you for all the answers I learnt something new today. I settled for @Rawling suggestion of using a IReadOnlyList<T>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `IList<IDataRecord>` should let you add *any* `IDataRecord` to it; your list only lets you add `VallDataData`.

If you only need to read from the list, try using `IReadOnlyList<IDataRecord>` instead, as it is actually covariant.

Comment: Also, if you need indexer access (`fileRecord.DataRecords[0]` for example) you can also use the newer `IReadOnlyList<IDataRecord>`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Oh, awesome. I need to start using those.

Comment: Yea, `IReadonlyList<out T>` and `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>` where added in 4.5, both very useful (Too bad the dictionary version is not co-variant, but it makes sense sence it needs to be able to be a `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` and `KeyValuePair` can't be co-variant do to it not being a interface)

Answer (score 2):

[`IList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6(v=vs.110).aspx) is neither contravariant or covariant, because it has `T` both on input and output positions in its methods. That is why you get:

> Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IList'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

You should use either [`Cast`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx) or `ToList<T>` here.

If `IList<T>` were covariant or contravariant it should have either `in` or `out` before it's generic parameter T (see [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx) for example), but it is not the case.

Comment: This is a valid way of doing it too, if the user does actually want a `IList<IDataRecord>` he can add and remove any type of `IDataRecord` from.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot implicitly convert `List<Derived>` to `IList<Base>` because `IList<T>` is not Covariant (see [about covariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx)).

`IList<T>` is not covariant because it is mutable (see [this SO question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832094/covariance-and-ilist))

Consider the following *if it was covariant*:

```
public interface INameable 
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public class Person : INameable
{
    public Person(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
}

public class Star : INameable
{
    public Star(string name, int brightness)
    {
         Name = name;
         Brightness = brightness;
    }

    public int Brightness { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

}

public void MyMethod() 
{
    List<Person> people = new List<Person> { new Person("Sam"), new Person("Pop") };

    // note: I *cannot* do the following, but let's pretend I can
    IList<INameable> nameables = people;

    // note: nameables and people technically reference the same object
    // so consider what happens when I do this:
    nameables.Add(new Star("Alpha Centauri", 9000));

    // nameables is cool, but oh man, my people list is now totally messed up. Sabotage!
    // Thanks goodness for covariance in generics!
}
```

In summary, I would consider using `IEnumerable<T>` in place of `IList<T>` when you can. It's typically good practice to not let your objects be mutable (unless you really want them to be).

Example of immutability (from OP's code):

```
public class FileRecord
{
    public IEnumerable<IDataRecord> DataRecords { get; private set; }
    public IEnumeable<ImageFile> Images { get; private set; }
    public string IndexFileName { get; private set; }
    public string IndexFilePath { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: I had them initially as IEnumerable<T>, but I need to repeatedly access the Count property which doesn't exist in IEnumerable.<T>, I have settled for using IReadOnlyCollection<T> which more clearly represents the access I'll have on this list anyway and as I now know... Is covariant. Thanks.

Comment: @franklores: Ok. Just so you're informed, `IEnumerable<T>` does have a `Count()` in LINQ, which is optimized if the backing implementation implements `ICollection<T>` (see this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/853478/1708147). Either way, you're good so don't feel like you *have* to use `IEnumerable`.