# how to typecast Parent to Child with IList in C#

Tags: c#, list, run-time-polymorphism

Below is my DTO in C#.Net

```
public class Movie
{
 public int Id { get; set;}
 public IEnumerable<Blog> Blogs {get; set;}
}


public class Blog
{
  public int Id { get; set;}
}
public class BlogCat1 : Blog
{
  public string SomeProp1 { get; set;}
}

public class BlogCat2 : Blog
{
  public string SomeProp2 { get; set;}
}
```

Now when I initialize Blogs with Child entity with IEnumerable No error or explicit conversion required.
i.e.,

```
movieObj.Blogs = new List<BlogCat1>(); // fine no error
movieObj.Blogs = new List<BlogCat2>(); // fine no error
```

But for some reason, I need to use IList instead of IEnumerable as

```
 public IList<Blog> Blogs {get; set;}
```

but when updated so & tried to assign with the Child Entity

```
movieObj.Blogs = new List<BlogCat1>(); // error CompileTime Error

movieObj.Blogs = (Ilist<BlogCat1)new List<BlogCat1>(); // error
```

how to map `IList<Parent>` with `IList<Child>` ?

Thanks!

Comment: `IEnumerable` is [convariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance), while IList isn't. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832094/covariance-and-ilist) can give you some inspiration.

Comment: Imagine if you will 
movieObj.Blogs = new List<BlogCat1>(); movieObj.Blogs.Add(new BlogCat2());
what should happen? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance

Comment: @RichardFriend makes sense. Thanks!