# Why isn't List<List<int>> implictly converted to IList<IList<int>?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, roslyn

Why can a `List<List<int>` not be passed to a function which accepts an `IList<IList<int>`?

I can see how this type conversion may be hard to infer. However, it seems to work fine when converting to an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>` or starting with a `int[][]`, as you can see from my test program. I can't understand why some of these type conversions are infered, when others are not.

```
 internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[][] jaggedArray = { new int[]  { 0 } };
            Console.WriteLine(AcceptsIEnumerable(jaggedArray));
            Console.WriteLine(AcceptsIList(jaggedArray));

            List<List<int>> listArray = new() { new List<int> { 0 } };
            Console.WriteLine(AcceptsIEnumerable(listArray));
            // Not valid! Why?
            //Console.WriteLine(AcceptsIList(listArray));
        }

        static bool AcceptsIEnumerable(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> x)
        {
            return true;
        }
        static bool AcceptsIList(IList<IList<int>> x)
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: TLDR: you can't do this. Suppose you could, then I could take your list of `List<object>`s and insert into it a `object[]` array, which although it is a `IList<object>` it is not a `List<object>`, therefore it would be an unsafe typecast. You need covariance for this to work, and that only works with readonly interfaces. So `IList<IReadOnlyList<object>>` or `IReadOnlyList<IReadOnlyList<object>>` would work. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832094/covariance-and-ilist

Comment: Read up on _covariance_ and _contravariance_

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks for the tip about readonly interfaces! That's the key difference I couldn't see.