# Generic interfaces and inheritance in .NET

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface

I have the following scenario that involves a couple of interfaces as below

```
    internal interface ITranslation
    {
        string LanguageCode { get; set; }
        string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

Any object that hold translations will implement the `ITranslation` interface. Some of these objects can have synonyms as well, so I have another interface

```
    internal interface ITranslationWithSynonmys : ITranslation
    {
        IList<string> Synonyms { get; set; }
    }
```

Next step I have defined `ITranslatable<T>` interface for any object that has translations and can be translated in different languages

```
    internal interface ITranslatable<T> where T : ITranslation
    {
        IList<T> Translations { get; set; }
    }
```

while when there are synonyms involved the `ITranslatableWithSynonyms<T>` looks like this

```
    internal interface ITranslatableWithSynonyms<T> : ITranslatable<T> where T : ITranslationWithSynonmys
    {
        IList<T> SynonymTanslations { get; set; }
    }
```

Concrete implementations of `ITranslation` and `ITranslationWithSynonmys` would be

```
    internal class BaseTranslation : ITranslation
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
    }

    internal class BaseTranslationWithSynonmys : ITranslationWithSynonmys
    {
        public IList<string> Synonyms { get; set; }
        public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

while an entity that can be translated would be

```
    internal class TranslatableEntity : ITranslatable<ITranslation>
    {
        public IList<ITranslation> Translations { get; set; }
    }
```

and if it has synomys

```
    internal class TranslatableWithSynonymsEntity : ITranslatableWithSynonyms<ITranslationWithSynonmys>
    {
        public IList<ITranslationWithSynonmys> SynonymTanslations { get; set; }
        public IList<ITranslationWithSynonmys> Translations { get; set; }
    }
```

Next, I'm creating a service that can translate any object that implements `ITranslatable<T>` and I have defined it as

```
    internal class TranslationService
    {
        internal string Translate(ITranslatable<ITranslation> translatable, string languageCode)
        {
            // It will iterate through the Translations list to find the correct translation
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Now, when I try to use the service, I'm writting

```
var translationService = new TranslationService();
var translatableEntity = new TranslatableEntity();
var translatableWithSynonymsEntity = new TranslatableWithSynonymsEntity();
string x = translationService.Translate(translatableEntity, "en");
string y = translationService.Translate(translatableWithSynonymsEntity, "en");
```

and here the last line `translationService.Translate(translatableWithSynonymsEntity, "en")` fails to compile with *error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'TestInheritance.TranslatableWithSynonymsEntity' to 'TestInheritance.ITranslatable<TestInheritance.ITranslation>'*

It's true that `TranslatableWithSynonymsEntity` doesn't implement `ITranslatable<ITranslation>`, but it implements `ITranslatableWithSynonyms<ITranslationWithSynonmys>` with both `ITranslatableWithSynonyms<T>` inheriting from `ITranslatable<T>` and `ITranslationWithSynonmys` inheriting from `ITranslation`.

I can get the code to compile by having `TranslatableWithSynonymsEntity` implement both `ITranslatableWithSynonyms<ITranslationWithSynonmys>` and `ITranslatable<ITranslation>`, but that means managing two lists and it doesn't look *clean*.

```
    internal class TranslatableWithSynonymsEntity : ITranslatableWithSynonyms<ITranslationWithSynonmys>, ITranslatable<ITranslation>
    {
        public IList<ITranslationWithSynonmys> SynonymTanslations { get; set; }
        public IList<ITranslationWithSynonmys> Translations { get; set; }
        IList<ITranslation> ITranslatable<ITranslation>.Translations { get; set; }
    }
```

Is there a way to avoid this? Or am I taking a wrong approach?

Thank you

Comment: It looks like you can drop generics altogether - it's not clear what you need them for here?

Comment: I need generics because ITranslatable can have a list of ITranslation or any interface inheriting from ITranslation. I don't want it to return always ITranslatable. As you can see in the case of TranslatableWithSynonymsEntity  it returns IList<ITranslationWithSynonmys>

Comment: Now, due to your ITranslatableWithSynonyms and ITranslatable interfaces specifying some `IList<T> Something {get;set;}` properties, it's not possible to make them covariant. So, you either have to find a way to avoid such properties with setters and some non-covariant interface<T> type as the property's return type which do not allow making the interface co-variant, or you have to find a different class/interface design altogether...

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832094/covariance-and-ilist one option would be to use IReadOnlyList<out T> in place of IList<T>. Probably I can adapt that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic parameters are invariant by default, in the method `Translate` you want the type to be `<ITranslation>`, so you must provide a type whose (or its parents') generic parameter is exactly `<ITranslation>`.

In your example you cannot simply mark the parameter as covariant because it contains a property has both getter and setter.

Since the problem is the generic parameter, to solve the problem, don't specify one, in fact you have already constrained the generic parameter.

```
interface ITranslatable<T> where T : ITranslation
```

The method (or the class) just need to be declared with the same constraint.

```
internal string Translate<T>(ITranslatable<T> translatable, string languageCode)
     where T : ITranslation
```

Comment: In that case Translations property of TranslatableWithSynonymsEntity  will return   IList<ITranslation> and I'll have to cast it any place I want to access the elements of the list as ITranslationWithSynonmys. That's what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: actually you're right. Changing the signature to         
``` 
internal string Translate<T>(ITranslatable<T> translatable, string languageCode)
            where T : ITranslation
``` 
works